# Integration w.r.t nondegenerate Gaussian probability measure on $X$ with mean $0$

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lebesgue-integral

Suppose that $X$ is a Banach space. Denote $\gamma$ as a nondegenerate Gaussian probability measure on $X$ with mean $0$.

Question: Is it true that

$$\int_X{d\gamma(t)}=0?$$

Or we have

$$\int_X{d\gamma(t)}=1?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\gamma$ is a probability measure, you have $$\gamma(X) = \int_X \mathrm{d}\gamma(t) = 1$$
and the mean is
$$\int_X t \, \mathrm{d}\gamma(t) = 0.$$
(This is the zero element of $X$).